# android:editTextBackground requires API level 11 (current min is 7)

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android. I created an application for api7 to api19 using support library and Theme.AppCompat.Light theme and I'm trying now to apply a custom theme to it but I get the error `android:editTextBackground requires API level 11 (current min is 7)` on the second line of *themes_wvtheme.xml*. I would like to know the correct edittext attribute for api<11.

This is my *style.xml*:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

This is my custom theme *themes_wvtheme.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/wvtheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>

<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/wvtheme_btn_check_holo_light</item>

<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/wvtheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>

<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonWVTheme</item>

<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonWVTheme</item>

<item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/wvtheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>

<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/wvtheme_activated_background_holo_light</item>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: change t6he minSDKversion to 11 in androidmanifest of your project

Comment: Are you really gonna support API Level 7 (Eclair)? If not change it to higher level in your case API 11. You might want to consider to support API level that has significant number of users. You may want to set minSDK to ICS since Froyo and below device are almost non existent in this day and age.

Comment: I have built all the application to support android api7 upwards and this is the last problem to solve for everything to be ok.the target users are susceptible of using old devices

Comment: i want to know if there is a background parameter in edittext for api 7 or 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a style for your EditTexts, and specify a `background` attribute for it. That is, in `style.xml` put something like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/wvtheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <!-- ..other attributes.. -->
</style>
```

Then, in your app theme, add the line:

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.EditText</item>
```

The oldest API level I've built for using this approach is 8, but it should work for API level 7 as well.

Comment: some poeple find it's better to downvote than answer the actual question.the question was quite clear and i googled for it but actually did not find the answer and besides i'm new to android as i said.Many downvoted questions saved my life until now

Comment: @steveenzoleko a bunch of trolls, ain't that so :) ?